# Getting cached response when fetching stack details from openstack using npm pkgcloud getStack() method

Tags: openstack, pkgcloud

I am using the below code block to fetch the details of a particular stack. The code is working fine and I am getting the stack details. But the problem is that I have to get the status of the stack after stack creation is completed. I am using the same code block as below but I am getting a cached response; by a cached response I mean that the stack status which I get even after the stack creation is complete is `"Create in Progress"` instead of `"Create Complete"`. Can someone tell why such behavior?

How to get the actual stack details instead of the cached details?

Can something be done OpenStacktack end or on pkgcloud end?

```
var stackID = '162472b2-e453-4e2c-919a-0150d0fb878d';
openstack_client_orchestration.getStack(stackID,function(err,stack)
{
   var temp_data = JSON.stringify(stack);
    console.log(stack['outputs'][0].output_value);
    console.log(stack.name);
    console.log(stack.id);
    console.log(stack.status); 
    console.log(stack.outputs);
 // var keys = Object.keys(stack.outputs);
   //for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
     //  var key = keys[i];
       //console.log(key, stack.outputs[key]);
   //} 
   });
```